# assertion from valgrind mc_main.c

Tags: valgrind

My valgrind runs reports errors like this

```
Memcheck: mc_main.c:8292 (mc_pre_clo_init): Assertion 'MAX_PRIMARY_ADDRESS == 0x1FFFFFFFFFULL' failed.
```

What does this mean? Is it a valgrind internal error or an error from my program?

Comment: Which platform is this? And which version of Valgrind?

Answer (score 1):

This is a valgrind internal error. This is very weird, as this failed
assertion is a self check done very early on.
You should file a bug on valgrind bugzilla, reporting all the needed
details (version, platform, ...)

Answer (score 0):

From the Valgrind source code (from git HEAD)

```
/* Only change this.  N_PRIMARY_MAP *must* be a power of 2. */

#if VG_WORDSIZE == 4

/* cover the entire address space */
#  define N_PRIMARY_BITS  16

#else

/* Just handle the first 128G fast and the rest via auxiliary
   primaries.  If you change this, Memcheck will assert at startup.
   See the definition of UNALIGNED_OR_HIGH for extensive comments. */
#  define N_PRIMARY_BITS  21

#endif


/* Do not change this. */
#define N_PRIMARY_MAP  ( ((UWord)1) << N_PRIMARY_BITS)

/* Do not change this. */
#define MAX_PRIMARY_ADDRESS (Addr)((((Addr)65536) * N_PRIMARY_MAP)-1)

...

tl_assert(MAX_PRIMARY_ADDRESS == 0x1FFFFFFFFFULL);
```

So it looks like something has been changed that shouldn't have been.