# What to do with valgrind error Assertion 'VG_IS_WORD_ALIGNED(a)' failed

Tags: c++, linux, valgrind

Automatic test for our program picked up very rare problem with 1 module. Test consists of running under valgrind (valgrind-3.18.1) a sample program using our library. Sample program seems to finish correctly, but later valgrind starts complaining in following fashion:

```
[FooTest] (... redacted program stdout ...)
[FooTest] ==2== 
[FooTest] ==2== HEAP SUMMARY:
[FooTest] ==2==     in use at exit: 473,112 bytes in 4,756 blocks
[FooTest] ==2==   total heap usage: 27,292 allocs, 22,536 frees, 29,352,230 bytes allocated
[FooTest] ==2== 
[FooTest] 
[FooTest] Memcheck: mc_main.c:5765 (vgMemCheck_is_valid_aligned_word): Assertion 'VG_IS_WORD_ALIGNED(a)' failed.
[FooTest] 
[FooTest] host stacktrace:
[FooTest] ==2==    at 0x58042F3A: ??? (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
[FooTest] ==2==    by 0x58043067: ??? (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
[FooTest] ==2==    by 0x5804320B: ??? (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
[FooTest] ==2==    by 0x58010FC1: ??? (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
[FooTest] ==2==    by 0x580020C4: ??? (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
[FooTest] ==2==    by 0x58002427: ??? (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
[FooTest] ==2==    by 0x58002895: ??? (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
[FooTest] ==2==    by 0x58002B42: ??? (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
[FooTest] ==2==    by 0x5800437F: ??? (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
[FooTest] ==2==    by 0x5800F2C2: ??? (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
[FooTest] ==2==    by 0x580B2214: ??? (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
[FooTest] ==2==    by 0x580E4D53: ??? (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
[FooTest] 
[FooTest] sched status:
[FooTest]   running_tid=1
[FooTest] 
[FooTest] 
[FooTest] Note: see also the FAQ in the source distribution.
[FooTest] It contains workarounds to several common problems.
[FooTest] In particular, if Valgrind aborted or crashed after
[FooTest] identifying problems in your program, there's a good chance
[FooTest] that fixing those problems will prevent Valgrind aborting or
[FooTest] crashing, especially if it happened in m_mallocfree.c.
[FooTest] 
[FooTest] If that doesn't help, please report this bug to: www.valgrind.org
[FooTest] 
[FooTest] In the bug report, send all the above text, the valgrind
[FooTest] version, and what OS and version you are using.  Thanks.
```

I am completely unable to reproduce it locally, on build server it only occurred rarely. Compiling and running sample program with address or ub sanitizer didn't show any problems.
Reviewing the code didn't find any issues.

What does this error mean? Is valgrind even complaing about my program, or is it valgrind crash? In any case do you have any pointers how to find the issue?

EDIT

System on build server where it happens (occasionally) is some containerized Linux x86_64 (possibly Alma Linux 9, but I don't know whether valgrind is from official repo or not).

I checked valgrind code around mc_main.c:5765 but didn't understand what it does. I also verified that latest version of valgrind didn't modify the method that asserts. I saw the [FAQ](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html) but didn't find anything that helps me.

Sample program feeds some string to rapidjson library and later one of the values in json goes to openssl's `EVP_DecodeBlock`. The value in question happens to be invalid base64, but from what I can tell both rapidjson and openssl should handle it fine.

EDIT2

Colleague helped me find most likely debug symbols for valgrind. I'm not sure they are perfect match, but at least part around mc_main.c:5765 seems to fit. Reminder - this is [valgrind-3.18.1](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=valgrind.git;a=blob;f=memcheck/mc_main.c;h=d268d7e52b62af1dbd6e4ae6c148eeb43c6cbc7c;hb=42b08ed5bda9aa2b18d826a99a10312f826e3b85#l5765)

```
addr2line -fpCie ./usr/lib/debug/usr/libexec/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux.debug   0x58042F3A 0x58043067 0x5804320B 0x58010FC1 0x580020C4 0x58002427 0x58002895 0x58002B42 0x5800437F 0x5800F2C2 0x580B2214 0x580E4D53  | column -t
show_sched_status_wrk                  at coregrind/m_libcassert.c:406                             
report_and_quit                        at coregrind/m_libcassert.c:477                             
vgPlain_assert_fail                    at coregrind/m_libcassert.c:543                             
vgMemCheck_is_valid_aligned_word       at memcheck/mc_main.c:5765           (discriminator  1)
heuristic_reachedness.constprop.0      at memcheck/mc_leakcheck.c:685
lc_push_without_clique_if_a_chunk_ptr  at memcheck/mc_leakcheck.c:954                              
lc_scan_memory                         at memcheck/mc_leakcheck.c:1365                             
scan_memory_root_set                   at memcheck/mc_leakcheck.c:2182                             
vgMemCheck_detect_memory_leaks         at memcheck/mc_leakcheck.c:2391                             
mc_fini                                at memcheck/mc_main.c:8025                                  
shutdown_actions_NORETURN              at coregrind/m_main.c:2242           (discriminator  2)
run_a_thread_NORETURN                  at coregrind/m_syswrap/syswrap-linux.c:201
```

Comment: You don't provide enough information. What OS is this on? What does the test exe do? Are there other errors before this? It also looks like you are using a crappy Linux distro that has ignored the Valgrind developers advice to not ship stripped Valgrind binaries. Thanks to that there is no useful callback information at the crash site. Try building Valgrind from source and see if you can get a useful callstack.

Comment: The error happens during leak checking but that is about all that I can say.

Comment: "Note: see also the FAQ in the source distribution." -- did you check that? Have you inspected the code in `mc_main.c`? You are a few versions behind, have you tried updating Valgrind? Have you tried to recompile with debug symbols so that you get a usable stacktrace?

Comment: Related question https://stackoverflow.com/a/49835919/1387438 If you are using modern compiler I really recommend you to replace valgrind with sanitizers provided by compiler. It is easy to use (just add build flags).

Comment: @MarekR I'm not knocking the sanitizers, but unless you are using clang(++) and you can rebuild all of your dependent libraries (including libstdc++ and libc++) then you won't be able to use MSAN. Needing one or more special builds can also be a major problem (e.g. if you have a very large regression test suite).

Comment: @MarekR and again the link that you post has absolutely nothing to do with the OP.

Comment: Also _are there any other errors_? If your test exe is borked it can corrupt Valgrind's internals.

Comment: there are no other errors from valgrind, asan nor ubsan.

Comment: OK. I can'r do any more without a callstack or a small reproducer.